# How to open a local file with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, jnlp, accesscontrolexception

I've wrote a mp3 player and works fine in desktop mode (jar file). But when I try to run it via web an AccessControlException is thrown.

I had the same problem with the buttons graphics, and I solved it by uploading the graphics to an image server. Obviously I don't want to do the same with the songs. I want that any user can play their local songs, using a FileChooser.

¿How can I do this?

.....................................................................................................

More details:

The AccessControlException exception occurs here:

```
try
{
    // f is a File
    listaCanciones.getItems().add(f.getName());     //adding filename to a ListView (works fine)
    mp3Tmp = new Media(f.toURI().toString());       //creating a Media object
    listaReproduccion.add(new MediaPlayer(mp3Tmp)); //creating MediaPlayer object and adding it to a playlist
}
```

The exception's toString() is:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "I:\music\song.mp3" "read")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the local filesystem from a jnlp deployed application:

1. Request appropriate permissions in your jnlp file.
2. Sign the application.
3. The user has to [accept a dialog prompt](http://java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml) to grant those permissions to your application.

You can find more information in the [Java client deployment guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/toc.html):

- [3.2.4 Run in Sandbox Unless Signed and Trusted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deploy_overview.html#CEGDDIGC).
- [5.6 Sign the JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABJGFBH).
- [jnlp security element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#security) - you shouldn't need to tweak this directly, instead you should specify the required permissions using your packaging tool (e.g. `-allpermissions` for the [javapackager tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)).

Note: an application which is not deployed via jnlp does not run in a sandbox and does not have the above requirements.

Oracle supply a [FAQ for code signing](http://java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml).